# viewing the progress of a SqlSyncScopeProvisioning operation

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, microsoft-sync-framework

I am getting an error during sync provisioning about a primary key and I would like to monitor what table it fails on. Is there a way to display the table collection as it builds the scope and applies it to the database?

Answer (score 0):

A good alternative is to use generate script API in provisioning to generate SQL script and run it manually to check where it fails.